# Find and move command in Unix throwing some error

Tags: shell, unix, find, exec, mv

When I run this queries manually, it throws an error.

Actual command in Script:

```
find $TMPDIR/tmp0 -name "*.W080" -type d -exec mv -f {} $TMPDIR/w0 \; 
find $TMPDIR/w0 -name "*.TIF" -type f -exec mv -f {} $FINALDIR/$DATE/W080-RF \;
```

Error throws at runtime:

```
find: 0652-081 cannot change directory to </sapxchange/OPENTEXT/Symcor/tmp/tmp0/batch.B75355.L9135.D20150326.T022818.W080>:
: A file, file system or message queue is no longer available.
find: 0652-081 cannot change directory to </sapxchange/OPENTEXT/Symcor/tmp/tmp0/batch.B75356.L9135.D20150326.T022818.W080>:
: A file, file system or message queue is no longer available.
```

P.S – Please note even after above error comes in runtime, the job completes and process the data…

Comment: You're looking in a temporary directory ($TMPDIR/). My guess is it contains files used during the run of the program. So If you run the query alone, there may be no more files or not accessible that easily. Again, just my thoughts, don't have time to look at it deeper

Comment: advice, especially in questions  of  find ... -exec:   lose the exec from the command and see if there is any data (e.g. files) to work on,   then see if there is anything in TMPDIR, TMPDIR/tmp0, and finally does TMPDIR/w0 exist and with write permissions ,   ditto FINALDIR/DATE/W080-RF?

Answer (score 0):

I think find is looking for files in the subdirs of `/sapxchange/OPENTEXT/Symcor/tmp/tmp0/batch.B75355.L9135.D20150326.T022818.W080` and suddenly the whole dir has been removed.
So find doesn't understand where is is searching.

When all W080 files are at the same level, try without find:
`mv -f $TMPDIR/tmp0/*.W080 $TMPDIR/w0`